# Why does Emacs use C-a for moving to the beginning of a line (home)?

Tags: key-bindings

I am making a tutorial about Emacs and do not know how to explain the reason why `C-a` is chosen as the keyboard to move the cursor to the beginning of a line?

Everything with `C-b, C-f, C-n, C-p, C-e` make sense for me, as they stand for `backward, forward, next, previous, end`

But why `C-a` stands for `home`?

My guess is that `home` can be understood as `begin`, but `b` is already used for `backward`, hence `a`, which stands before `b`, is chosen.

Does anyone know a better explanation?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180113/56415 tries to address the historical side of this choice.

Comment: This is just a guess, but I would imagine the reason being `C-b` (which would stand for "beginning of line") was already taken by "backward".

Answer (score 1):

`a` is at start of alphabet, and `C-a` moves to start of line (and mnemonic letters, e.g. `s`, were taken).

More importantly, it is a common command that can conveniently be typed with one hand, as `a` is on the left hand side of the keyboard near the control key. Ancient keyboards placed it just below `TAB`, where you might find Caps Lock nowadays.

In common sequences, left hand might type `C-a` or `C-e`, immediately followed by right hand typing `C-o`, `RET`, or prev / next arrows or control characters. It is good to make such a frequently used navigation command easy to type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! @YoungFrog also gave a pointer to the history of `C-a` in `bash`